# MIPS 2D Array print as a matrix

Tags: assembly, mips, multidimensional-array

I have a question regarding arrays in MIPS assembly.
My 2D array is represented by large 1D array ( for example, 2x2 array is just a 1D array with 4 "cells").

However, I have problems when I try to print my 2D array as a matrix. I mean that if I have the array: 3x3 with the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 I would like to print it on 3 separate lines with 3 integers on each line and NOT on a single line or on 9 lines.

```
`
add $t3,$0,$0 # t3 = counter
la $s1,tableau #s1 = addresse of the begining of the array
AFFICHE_MAT:    
beq $t3,$t2, FIN #t3 = counter, t2 = total number of elements for the matrix
beq $t3,$t1 NEW_LINE #if we are at the end of a line, we'd like to print \n
lw $a0,($s1) #print the next number of the 2D array
addi $v0,$0,1
syscall
la $a0,intervalle #we print ' ' between all numbers
addi $v0,$0,4
syscall
addi $s1,$s1,4
addi $t3,$t3,1
j AFFICHE_MAT
```

`NEW_LINE:
    la $a0,NL
    addi $v0,$0,4
    syscall
    j AFFICHE_MAT
FIN:
    addi $v0,$0,10
    syscall`

The problem is that when I make the test whether I am at the end of a line

```
beq $t3,$t1 NEW_LINE #if we are at the end of a line, we'd like to print \n
```

I jump to NEW_LINE, then from NEW_LINE I jump to AFFICHE_MAT
`NEW_LINE:
    la $a0,NL
    addi $v0,$0,4
    syscall
    j AFFICHE_MAT`

but in AFFICHE_MAT I have lost the value of the counter.

If I don't test whether I am at the end of a line, I print the entire 2D array but on a single line.

Do you have any suggestion how can I fix this problem?
Thank you in advance
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem that you have is that after printing a newline you go back to the part that tests whether a newline should be print, which will be true again so you end printing infinite number of newlines.

You may fix it by jumping back to the instruction *after* the one that checks to see if a newline has to be print.

That would to add a label `AFTER_NEW_LINE`:

```
AFFICHE_MAT:    
  beq $t3,$t2, FIN #t3 = counter, t2 = total number of elements for the matrix
  beq $t3,$t1 NEW_LINE #if we are at the end of a line, we'd like to print \n
AFTER_NEW_LINE:
  lw $a0,($s1) #print the next number of the 2D array
```

and in the NEW_LINE subroutine change `j AFFICHE_MAT` with

```
  j AFTER_NEW_LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was the problem. I was not jumping to the correct place after printing the\n symbol. Right now the program prints the matrix well!

Thank you!